# If I update memory cache using the Set method, with an absolute expiry, will this mean the expiry is extended?

Tags: c#, caching, memorycache

I'm using [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) to store a data table, which contains about 60 rows. Sometimes I want to 'refresh' only part of the table. So I get a the collections of rows I want to refresh based of an id like this:

```
var cachedDataSet = this.cache.Get(CacheKey) as DataSet;

var dataRows = cachedDataSet.Tables["MyTable"]
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(x => x.Field<int>("Id") == MyId)
                            .ToList<DataRow>();
```

I then do some checks against this and based off the results of this will choose to get the data from the DB, remove the current rows from the cachedDataSet and add the new data. I try to do it like this:

```
var refreshedData = GetMyData(Id);
foreach (var row in dataRows)
{
    cachedDataSet.Tables["MyTable"].Rows.Remove(row);
}

foreach (var row in refreshedData.Tables["MyTable"].Rows)
{
    cachedDataSet.Tables["MyTable"].Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
}
```

Finally, I add the cachedDataSet back into the cache using the [`Set` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780572(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(12);
this.cache.Set(CacheKey, cachedDataSet, policy);
```

So, my main question is that if I extract the cache out into a dataset, amend it and then use the `Set` method using a new CacheItemPolicy, will this effectively reset the absolute expiration? My understanding is that by using the set method this will overwrite the existing cached item with the new if it exists and insert it if it doesn't. So, my guess is that it will overwrite the cache policy. If so, is there a way of not overwriting the absolute expiration whilst overwriting the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will update expiration time. What you can do is store expiration time together with item itself, in cache. So

```
class CachedDataSet {
    public DateTime ExpiresAt {get;set;}
    public DataSet DataSet {get;set;}
}
```

Then when refreshing, you first get this item from cache and use it's `ExpiresAt` as new `AbsoluteExpiration` value.

Comment: This sounds like a plan. How do I access the absolute expiry of a cached item?

Comment: You cannot do that (no API for that), that is why I suggest to store that expiration time together with item itself (as described).

Comment: Would the ExpiresAt property not be better as a DateTimeOffset seeing as the AbsoluteExpiration property is the same as that? As I understand it the DateTimeOffset is a point in time, so should be usable as a reference point for expiry.

Comment: Yes can be DateTimeOffset (though both DateTime and DateTimeOffset represent point in time, just DateTimeOffset also contains information about timezone).